# How to implement Java method returning a generic type parametrized with array in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have an interface with the following method in Java:

```
<E> Encoder1<E[]> arrayArg(Encoder1<? super E> elemEncoder);
```

I'm trying to implement it in Scala with the following declaration:

```
override def arrayArg[E](elemEncoder: Encoder1[_ >: E]): Encoder1[Array[E]]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(38, 16) overriding method arrayArg in trait Encoders of type [E](elemEncoder: redradishes.encoder.expr.Encoder1[_ >: E])redradishes.encoder.expr.Encoder1[Array[E with Object]];
 method arrayArg has incompatible type
  override def arrayArg[E](elemEncoder: Encoder1[_ >: E]): Encoder1[Array[E]] = ???
               ^
```

What is wrong with my Scala method signature?

Comment: Have you tried changing the signature to match the expected one in the error message (i.e. adding `with Object` to the `E` in the return type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4390

I'm not sure I fully understand why, but you need to specify `E with Object` in return value for it to compile. The error informs you about that. Probably this is because in java you cannot use primitive types (`AnyVal`) as the generic parameter, but in scala you can so you need to specify that `E` extends `Object` to align it with Java rules. Still I'm not sure why this situation is so special.

If you are uncomfortable with `Object`, `E with AnyRef` also seem to work.